# Granger causality

Tags: time-series, self-study, references, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I have a variable $A$ which Granger causes a variable $B$, and a variable $C$, separately.

Since A and B are very similar in nature, I should expect that $B$ granger caused $C$ as well. Anyway when I perform the test I can't reject the null hypothesis of no causality between them.

Am I missing by any chance something about the theory and the "math" behind the test?

Comment: Why do you think this is true? And can you come up with a counter-example where it is false? Also read the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) on the `self-study` tag and figure out if adding it is appropriate.

Comment: Since the statement (1) "$A$ Granger-causes $B$ and $C$" refers to $B$ and $C$ symmetrically--they can be interchanged without changing the meaning at all--then if you *could* conclude "$B$ Granger-causes $C$" then you could also conclude "$C$ Granger-causes $B$".  These two statements allow you logically to deduce that $B$ and $C$ "Granger-cause" each other.  (Note that the actual meaning of "Granger-causes" is irrelevant to this argument.)  Does it make sense that statement (1) could imply such a conclusion?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have miswritten my question. I meant that A causes B, and A causes C but separately. In other words, I perform two different test in which I verify the causality between and A and B and between A and C.

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a self-study question, I will give you some hints rather than a full answer.

To falsify a conjecture, you only need to find a counterexample. Let us see how easy (or difficult) it is.

- You can formulate Granger noncausality in terms of restrictions in a VAR model.
- Take the simplest VAR model -- a VAR(1) -- for a trivariate system and see what minimal restrictions are sufficient for $A \not\xrightarrow{Granger} \{B,C\}$.
- Consider whether these restrictions imply $B \not\xrightarrow{Granger} C$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't made myself clear in my first question. I did not mean that I have a trivariate system.

Comment: @James, well, this actually does not change the essence and the answer still holds.

Comment: @James, so, is the answer clear? Do you need another hint?